# Jythoon/Java - I can import from .class files, but not .jar files

Tags: java, jython, importerror

Maybe the answer is simple, but it's not clear to me.

I have folowed the suggestions about the $CLASSPATH; I have ensured that my system is pointing to the correct JDK (OpenJDK8); I have tried within NetBeans and from Jython interactive sessions. I do have the Python/Jython Platform set up in NetBeans.

Yes, I am working from a book. This is what happens:

I create a class I want to import into Jython. I can successfully import any JDK classes. When I compile my .java file into a class, and put it in my CLASSPATH, I can import from it just fine. HOWEVER, when I create a jar file, and put it in the same CLASSPATH directory, I cannot import from the jar file. it gives me an InputError stating that `no module named <module>`.

Comment: For starters, you must add the .jar file to your classpath.  Adding the folder that contains the .jar file won't work.

Comment: We;;, I'll be. I knew the answer was simple, just couldn't see it. I did read about that and thought I did it right. Thanks for your help.